# Advice on when to use macros in C and when not to use

Tags: c, gcc, macros

If you see the gcc source code, you see that they use macros a lot. But generally, programmers are advised to avoid macros as they make the code harder to read.
Why then the gcc devs use so much of macros?

Please provide advice on when to use macros and when not to use.

Any references are welcome.

Comment: I haven't looked at all at the GCC code, but one thing to remember is that the rule against macros, like any other rule, has a second part which says that there are situations when you should break that rule, if you have good reason to do so, and if you know what you are doing.

Comment: if you can write a function for what you want to do then write a function for it. otherwise write a macro.

Comment: @Brandin So you do mean whatever you can write using functions, you should NOT define using macros at all?

Comment: @TemPora why would you write a macro for something that works just as well as a function?

Comment: @Brandin that is what I want to know. That is what I asked in the question.